# Find factorial of each element in a list and multiply them

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have to calculate the factorial of each element in a list, multiply them, and save the result in an integer variable. I have the factorial function, but I don't know how to do these manipulations with a list.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about?

```
product = 1
for item in some_list:
    product *= factorial(item)
```

Comment: Or `functools.reduce(operator.mul, map(factorial, mylist))`, for those who either (a) like functional languages or (b) have been reading about Big Data and think MapReduce is awesome. Neither idea is totally without merit, but the Python docs claim that the for loop is more readable and so this answer is better especially for beginners.